# Inner Product: Proof Of Second & Third Axiom for Normed Linear Space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

An inner product space $E$ becomes a normed linear space when equipped with the norm $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}\,\,$
for all $x \in E$

I tried proving the above theorem myself by using the three properties of inner product to prove the three axioms/properties of normed linear spaces. I was able to establish the following:

N1: $\|x\|\geq0$

Proof:
$$\langle x,x\rangle\geq0$$ by definition
Therefore $$\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}\,\,\geq0$$

N2: $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$

Proof:
$$\langle\lambda x, \lambda x\rangle=\lambda\langle x, \lambda x\rangle$$
This was where I got stuck. Can I simplify further to this?
$$\lambda\langle x, \lambda x\rangle={\lambda}^2 \langle x, x\rangle$$
If I can, then I can proceed further. If not, please I need guidance.

N3: $\|x+y\|\leq\|x\|+\|y\|$

Proof:

I started with the relation: $$\|x+y\|=\sqrt{\langle x+y,x+y\rangle}$$
Thus $${\|x+y\|}^2=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle x, x+y\rangle+\langle y, x+y\rangle=\langle x, x\rangle+\langle x, y\rangle+\langle y, x\rangle+\langle y, y\rangle$$
This simplifies further to: $${\|x+y\|}^2={\|x\|}^2+\langle x, y\rangle+\bar{\langle y, x\rangle}+{\|x\|}^2$$
I got confused here too. 
How is $\langle x, y\rangle,+\bar{\langle y, x\rangle}=2\Re \langle x, y\rangle\leq 2\langle x, y\rangle $

I know this might seem trivial but I'd appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For condition 2, we have
$$ \langle \lambda x,\lambda x\rangle =\lambda^2\langle x,x\rangle $$
if the vector space is real, and
$$ \langle \lambda x,\lambda x\rangle =|\lambda|^2\langle x,x\rangle $$
if it is complex. In both cases we get $||\lambda x||=|\lambda|\cdot||x||$ after taking a square root.

To prove condition 3, you will need the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ |\langle x,y\rangle|\leq ||x||||y||$$
together with the fact that $\Re z\leq |z|$ for all complex numbers $z$.

Comment: Thanks carmichael561, your response were apt